# Can we self define a function in BigQuery? How to create a date parameter in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, function, google-bigquery, mysql-python

I am trying to calculate the turnover rate for my department through a period of time. For instance, I'd like to know the turnover rate from  01/01/2021 - 05/01/2021, the sample data is like this:

```
 UK        Status        HireDate        TermDate
BUV0060    TRM         01/23/2007       12/2/2015
BUV0098    TRM         11/13/2002       2/17/2017
BUV0439    TRM         04/17/2017       2/5/2018
202758     ACT         06/03/1996   
17033      TRM         07/01/2019       6/11/2020
92121      ACT         02/24/2020   
211343     ACT         04/11/2005
```

then my codes would be like :

```
SELECT *,
    Terms /((startheadcount + EndHeadcount) / 2) AS turnover
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            sum(
                (
                    CASE WHEN HireDate < '2021-01-01'
                    AND TermDate >= '2020-05-01'
                    OR HireDate < '2021-01-01'
                    AND TermDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                )
            ) as startheadcount,
            sum(
                (
                    CASE WHEN HireDate >= '2021-01-01'
                    AND HireDate <= '2021-05-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                )
            ) as NewHires,
            sum(
                (
                    CASE WHEN TermDate >= '2020-01-01'
                    AND TermDate <= '2020-05-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                )
            ) as Terms,
            sum(
                (
                    CASE WHEN HireDate < '2021-05-01'
                    AND TermDate >= '2020-05-01'
                    OR Status = "ACT" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                )
            ) as EndHeadcount
        FROM
            `XXX.Turnover.Test` 
    )
```

Result:

```
startheadcount  NewHires    Terms   EndHeadcount    turnover    
4718              231        221       4698      0.046941376380628716
```

Just trying to make my life easier, I don't want to input the date range every time. So can we define a function only asking me to input date once, and the following codes will run automatically?

Thanks!!

Per gorden's answer, it shows :
[image]

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Just added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a function.  You can add parameters in a derived table.  I would recommend `COUNTIF()`:

```
SELECT *,
       Terms /((startheadcount + EndHeadcount) / 2) AS turnover
FROM (SELECT COUNTIF( t.HireDate < params.DateStart AND
                      (t.TermDate >= params.DateEnd OR t.TermDate IS NULL)
                    ) as startheadcount,
             COUNTIF(t.HireDate >= params.DateStart AND
                     t.HireDate <= params.DateEnd
                    ) as NewHires,
             COUNTIF(t.TermDate >= params.DateStart AND
                     t.TermDate <= params.DateEnd
                    ) as Terms,
             COUNTIF( t.HireDate < params.DateStart AND
                      t.TermDate >= params.DateEnd OR
                      t.Status = 'ACT'
                   ) as EndHeadcount
      FROM `XXX.Turnover.Test` t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT DATE('2021-05-01') as DateStart,
                   DATE('2021-05-01') as DateEnd
           ) params
     ) t
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you for your response. I could understand what you mean. But when I ran the codes, something went wrong. It  said Unrecognized Name: params. Is that something wrong with the join function? Can you help to look at it again?

Comment: @Sandy . . . `params` is the name of the derived table in the `FROM` clause.  It is quite well defined.

Comment: I did in in Bigquery, and it shows "SYNTAX ERROR ")" but got end of script". I could understand what you mean, but the codes just couldn't run....see the pic I added in the post.

Comment: @Sandy . . . I just missed that you are using a subquery.  An extra `) t` solves the problem.

Comment: Wow, it's fantastic. I really need to review the sql codes again. Time to go back to school...Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As a direct answer to your question - [BigQuery supports procedures](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting-concepts#writing_a_procedure).

Create a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE amazon.test(input_parameter int64, OUT out1 int64, OUT out2 int64)
BEGIN
  SET (out1, out2) = (select as struct input_parameter, 2 * input_parameter);
END;
```

Call a procedure:

```
DECLARE col1, col2 INT64;
CALL amazon.test(5, col1, col2);
SELECT col1, col2
```

[image]